# I want to display elements in JTextArea line by line. How to achieve that?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I'm creating a GUI to-do list with Swing. I have a button named "Display items" which will display the items in the ArrayList using a JTextArea.
The problem is, when I normally display ArrayList contents, they are displayed like,

```
[item1, item2, item3]
```

but I want them to be displayed as,

```
item1

item2

item3
```

Without GUI, the solution is simple. Creating a for loop and iterating through elements but I'm unable to do it in JTextArea.

I have tried iterating through for loop and displaying elements using

```
textarea.setText(String.valueOf(System.out.println(obj2.list(i))));
```

My ArrayList is in another class and obj2 is the object.

The way I'm doing it right now is,

```
textarea.setText(String.valueOf(obj2.list));
```

But it displays like `[item1, item2, item3]`

What do I need to do to get it like,

item1

item2

item3

```
b_disp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        for (int i = 0; i < obj2.list.size(); i++) {
            textarea.setText(String.valueOf(obj2.list));
         //area.setText(String.valueOf(System.out.println(obj2.list(i))));
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed` method:

Use `StringBuilder`

Iterate through arraylist

> Add item on current index to `StringBuilder`
>
> Append a new line charcter to `StringBuilder`

End

now use setText on Text Area and set String created using `StringBuilder`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: Use the `StringJoiner` class. It will append the delimiter for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
b_disp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            String text = obj2.list.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            textarea.setText(text);
        }
    }
});
```